# Browser Window Size during Visual Studio Debugging

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, browser

How can I force the window that opens when I run a website from Visual Studio to be maximized?  Everytime I run my site VS automatically resizes the window to something that seems arbitrary.

Comment: Which web browser are you using?

Answer (score 3):

After your browser window has been opened once (as not maximized) press the maximize button. Then HOLD ctrl key and press the close button ('X'). Then you may release the ctrl key.

Next time your window will be open as maximized (holding ctrl key while pressing close forces windows to remember the window's last state)

Answer (score 0):

Go into the project settings - Web - Start Action, and set it to be "External program" with start.exe and command line arguments of

/MAX http://localhost:12345/myproject/default.aspx  (or whatever)

This will open default.aspx in a maximized window, but only if you don't have any other IE windows open - if you do (and you have IE7) - you'll just get a tab in one of those windows instead.

This will probably keep your debugger from attaching to the iexplore process and may indeed return immediately because start.exe only runs for a second.  You may have to manually attach to the iexplore.exe process.

But it doesn't involve a bunch of window-manipulating JavaScript.

Comment: Where is start.exe?  I did a complete search of my hard drive and did not find it.

Comment: My mistake - it appears to be a command on Vista.  On earlier Windows OSes, it was a program that could be run.  Try entering 'start' into that box anyway, but it might not work.